# AJAX + PHP - Formulário de pedidos

Tags: php, ajax, front-end

Estou criando um formulário de contato onde usuário coloca seus dados pessoais e depois seleciona os produtos na qual quer um orçamento.

Os campos dos produtos são `select` e quantidade `input type="number"`.

Porém no PHP não pega esse Array, quando eu faço o envio por e-mail o produto vem vazio. **OBS**: Ele envia o email, mas chega vazio.

```
<select class="form-control escolha-produto" id="escolha-produto" name="produto[]" onchange="escolher_tamanho()">
    <option value="Botina Bombeiros">Botina Bombeiros </option>
    <option value="Botina Amarrar TBA 400">Botina Amarrar TBA 400 </option>
    <option value="Botina Elástico TBE 400">Botina Elástico TBE 400 </option>
    <option value="Coturno de Couro e Lona">Coturno de Couro e Lona </option>
    <option value="Sapato Amarrar Couro TSE 400">Sapato Amarrar Couro TSE 400 </option>
    <option value="Sapato Amarrar Misto TSA 400">Sapato Amarrar Misto TSA 400 </option>
    <option value="Sapato Elástico TSE 400">Sapato Elástico TSE 400</option>
    <option value="Sapato Social Feminino">Sapato Social Feminino</option>
</select>
```

Meu JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

   $.ajax({
      type : 'POST',
      url  : 'submit.php',
      data: $('#form').serialize(),
      success :  function(){
        console.log("Enviou");
        }
     });
   });
});
```

Meu PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['produto'])){
    $produto = $_POST ["produto];
    print_r($produto);
}
```

ENVIO PHPMAILER

```
    $mail->Body =  
                "Nome: ". $nome. "<br/>".
                "Endereço: ".$endereco. "<br/>".
                "Bairro: ".$bairro. "<br/>".
                "CEP: ".$cep. "<br/>".
                "Estado: ".$estado. "<br/>".
                "Cidade: ".$cidade. "<br/>".
                "CNPJ: ".$cnpj. "<br/>".
                "Telefone: ".$telefone. "<br/>".
                "Email: ".$email. "<br/>".
                "Produto: ".$produto. "<br/>".
                "Tamanho: ".$tamanho. "<br/>".
                "Quantidade: ".$quantidade. "<br/>";

    $enviado = $mail->Send();
```

Comment: Sua intenção é que o usuário possa escolher múltiplas opções?

Comment: A intenção é que ele possa escolher um produto  e o tamanho quantidade. Mas que ele possa clicar em um botão  e criar novos campos para fazer mais de um pedido.